# Looking for a good way to connect to Python Server IOT hardware behind a firewall and with JavaScript or python

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, iot, firewall

My plan is to make a docker server to run 24/7 on AWS ECS that the devices self report to on power up. So the MAC address and Public IP is know.

I know I could create a web socket connection, but I likely only need to communicate configs to these devices once every few days or so. That leads me to believe web sockets isn't the right way to go about this.

For context this for raspberry pies that I use to control fermentation temperature of beer fermentations. Right now everything is configured via JSON and runs with that config. All the data is logged to a database constantly. The end goal here is a React Dashboard to view the existing data, but also request current info from devices and push new configurations.

Just wondering how Sonos speakers and Phillips hue lights receive info from servers. Though I suppose those are usually triggered from inside the network.

Controller hardware is done, it just doesn't have communication yet.

Not really sure where to start other than to host within my own network, or use CloudFlared tunnel, but I'd like it to be possible to scale up this solution. Possibly to many users in different locations.